# Why Sunnies put "Karram Allahu Wajhah" after name of Ali ibn Abi Talib?

Tags: sunni, sahaba, ali

Sunni brothers normally use `"Rathi Allahu Anh"` after the name of Sahaba of Prophet Muhammad (PBUH). But in many cases use `"Karram Allahu Wajhah"` for Ali ibn Abi Talib.

For instance, on some tiles of Masjid Al Haram there are names of Sahaba, all of them are followed by `"Rathi Allahu Anh"`. But name of Ali is followed by `"Karram Allahu Wajhah"`.

What is the reason for respecting him differently from other Sahaba?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We say *Rady Allahu Anhu* (may Allah be pleased with him) when talking about any of the companions or the mothers of believers, including the caliphates.

We can say *Rady Allahu Anhu* about Ali, as we say *Karam Allah Wajhah* (may Allah bless his face) as he has never bowed to an idol.

Comment: +1 and accept "as he has never bowed to an idol". I think this is the reason behind respecting him differently.

Comment: Arabs used to raise their brothers children if their brothers had any trouble. Muhammad (PBUH) was raised at his uncle's house; Abo-Talib. Lately, Abo-Talib got old and poor, and he was gifted Ali. Ali was raised in the house of Muhammad (PBUH) and Khadija, as his father was too poor to raise all children. Ali was well raised and never worshiped any idol, which was a common practice at that time. So his face never bowed to an idol, his face is blessed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no particular compulsion to say "Radyallahu anhu" or "karam Allah wajhah". Even "Alaihis-Salam" (may peace be upon him) is fine. There is *NO* religious compulsion on saying what with whom.

It is simply a matter of conventions which can certainly be overridden with any other word which does not contradict the essence of Islam.

May peace be upon you too.

Comment: Assalaamu alaikum. I Welcome you to islam.stackexchange.com. I request you to please go through the FAQs and other answers by high reputation users on this site. Answers here are expected to be suitably referenced. Jazaakallah.

Comment: Dear, my point was that there is no reference to say what with whom.

Answer (score 0):

Karijites killed Ali(R.A).and they use to say may Allah blacken his face. Against this sunnies use to say May Allah honour his face(KARAMALLAHU VAJAHHU)

Comment: Good idea, but is there any reference?